# Finding the minimal number of affine schemes covering a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is there a method with which, given some scheme $X$, we can guess or even explicitly find the smallest/simplest possible affine covering? Furthermore, if such a method does exist, will it have a universal property/can we do it categorically?

Comment: @Arthur My motivation for this question is the fact that you can glue together 2 copies of $\mathbb{A}^1$ along $\text{Spec} k[T]_T$ to get the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$. This is all well and good, but what if for some reason we can not visualise $\mathbb{P}^1$. How would we know to test if the gluing above was the right one ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can take all affine open sets to get a natural covering (by definition of scheme). I'm not sure that would help you though. Perhaps you can expand a bit on the motivation in your comment.

Comment: @jgon I've edited the question's wording a bit. Hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific with your notion of "simplest/smallest". For example, if one picks any two distinct closed points $p_1,p_2\in\Bbb P^1_k$, then $\{\Bbb P^1_k\setminus p_1,\Bbb P^1_k\setminus p_2\}$ is an open cover. Which of these is simplest? This example also suggests that one cannot expect this process to be carried out by universal property: things satisfying universal properties are unique up to unique isomorphism, and it's easy to pick $k,p_1,p_2$ to violate that.

Comment: @KReiser I guess by "simple" I meant requiring the smallest number of affine schemes. But point taken, I get why my question was not phrased very well now.

Comment: Let an integral scheme of finite type $X = \bigcup_{j=1}^n Spec(R_j)$, your first question is a way to find if $n$ is minimal.

Comment: Any projective variety of dimension $n$ can be covered by $n+1$ affine open sets (and no less). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Mohan something like that, but for arbitrary schemes.

Comment: @reuns Yes that's a nice way of rephrasing my question.

Comment: Any Noetherian scheme of dimension $n$ can be covered by $n+1$ affine open sets, but of course this may not be the smallest without further information, for example the scheme could be affine to start with.

Comment: Dear @Mohan: why is that?

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg when you ask, I know I must have made a mistake. When I crossed my t's and dotted my i's, I realized my argument works only for quasi-projective schemes.

Comment: Thank you for for answering me, dear @Mohan.